# remove action for model in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have a problem. In my app I am using rails_admin gem. Everything is good except one thing. For some models I want to make possible only to delete them. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You have marked the answer as correct when it does not answer anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your rails_admin.rb file, you can add the default actions for your models in wich you can add exceptions as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345857/4129894).

Here is an exemple :

```
config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new do
      except ['SomeModel']
    end
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit do
      except ['SomeOtherModel']
    end
    delete
    show_in_app
end
```

Here is the link to the rails_admin documentation about actions : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions

Answer (score 1):

try changing in the file: config/initilizers/rails_admin.rb you can comment out the actions that you don't want to allow!

Comment: tryed this, but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CanCan: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancan

add this to your **ability.rb** file:

```
cannot :manage, Model # disable all actions for this model
can :destroy, Model # enable only to remove
```