# How to hide Add new option in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am customizing Rails Admin : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin , i need to disable/hide "Add new" option for some model.

[image]

Any help will save lot time for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27):

I use the following to achieve this on a specific model.  Hopefully, this helps:

```
config.actions do
  new do
    except ['Some Model']
  end
end
```

Comment: hello, but if in the url i add action, this allow access. Example `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/user/new` :/

Comment: @andres using the above rails_admin DSL will only remove the buttons from  the admin. As long as the routes still exist for that action, you will be able to do that action.

Comment: Just to be sure, you need to use a class name without single quotes. like `except [User]`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the [configuration documentation for actions](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions). By default, all actions are possible, including `new`. To customize the possible actions, in `config.actions` in `config/initilizers/rails_admin.rb`, list all the actions you want to support, leaving out the ones you don’t want to support. For example, here is a config block that allows all of the default actions except for `new`:

```rb
# config/initilizers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    # root actions
    dashboard
    # collection actions 
    index
    # `new` is NOT allowed
    export
    history_index
    bulk_delete
    # member actions
    show
    edit
    delete
    history_show
    show_in_app
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Rory , thanks for quick answer. Since it was in initializers its applied for all models. It hides all models new action , but I want it to hide new action in specific model.

Comment: In that case, I’m afraid I don’t know how to do it. Maybe some other part of the [RailsAdmin documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki) explains how. Maybe you have to look at the [source code](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) to see how to do it – [this part](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb#L15-L26) might be relevant. Or maybe RailsAdmin does not support that feature.

Comment: If necessary, there might be some hack that lets you run the initializer multiple times, letting you disable the `new` action when doing anything with that model and reenabling it when accessing any other model.

Comment: Cool, Its not possible only with Rails_Admin. We can achieve it easily using CAN-CAN , thanks for the your time.

Comment: @Senthil Now that you mention CanCan, I remember that the documentation has [example `can` calls related to the `new` action](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/New-action), though I hadn’t realized that that was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

To have multiple models, you must put each model in single quotes. For example, consider the following configuration:

```
config.actions do
  dashboard
  index do
    except ['Address']
  end
  new do
    except ['Address', 'Employee', 'Setting']
  end
  export
  show
  edit do
    except ['Employee']
  end
end
```

This means that:

- Addresses are not included on the navbar on the left
- You cannot add a new address employee or setting with the "add new" button
- There is no pencil icon in the index view for Employees for editing.
- If you had a `User` model you could see it in the navbar, edit it, and add a new one on the index page.
- You can export every model, but not bulk delete them.

Answer (score -3):

Implemented it with Cancan. You can refer to above answer to do it in rails admin way.

URL : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan

Comment: This is selected as the answer, but it is not true.  See my answer above.